# Issue facing while loading 3rd party Jquery library in lightning component

Tags: apex, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

I am trying to load 3rd party Jquery library using aura component in Salesforce lightning framework but facing below error message:

**Custom Script Eval error in 'ltng:require' [SecureDOMEvent: [object Event]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }]**

Anyone have any idea about this error message?